# Can't reassign value in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to populate `links` with values from `a` increased or decreased by `0.1`.
The output of the code below is the initial `links`... However, as soon as I delete these `0.1` code work perfectly fine. Why? How can I fix this?

```
a=np.random.randint(2, size=(9,9)) 
links = np.diag([1]*9) 
m = np.random.choice(9, 3, replace=False).tolist()
for j in m:
    row = a.take(j, axis=0).tolist()
    link_can = np.arange(9)
    link_can = link_can[link_can != j]
    link_can = np.random.choice(link_can, 3, replace=False).tolist()
for i in link_can:
    if row[i]==1:
        links[j, i] = row[i] - .1 
        links[i, j] = row[i] - .1
    else:
        links[j, i] = row[i] + .1 
        links[i, j] = row[i] + .1
links
```

Comment: What is your expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `links` array is of type `int`. Later, you perform `float` operations and insert a `float` into your array. `numpy` will cast this back to an `int`, losing your +/- 0.1 in the process.

You should convert your `array` to type `float` using [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), as demonstrated by this example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([0])
>>> arr
array([0])
>>> arr[0] = arr[0] + 0.1
>>> arr
array([0])
>>> arr = arr.astype(float)
>>> arr
array([0.])
>>> arr[0] = arr[0] + 0.1
>>> arr
array([0.1])
```

After changing the type of the `array` to `float`, the update works as expected.

Therefore, you may look to modify `links` as follows:

```py
links = np.diag([1]*9).astype(float)
```